# JPanel getpreferredsize() returns 10 instead of size of JFrame minus borders

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, size

I am trying to get the size of a JPanel so that I can subsequently calculate the correct dimension of graphics I plan to add. Since I have set the size of the JFrame to be (300, 200), I was expecting the getpreferredsize() function to return something slightly smaller than (300, 200) (i.e. minus border). However, the function simply returned 10 for both height and width. Please help.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame f = new Frame();
  }
}

class Frame extends JFrame {
  
  public Frame() {
    setSize(300, 200);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("Test Panel Size");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
    setVisible(true);  

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pack();
    drawPanel.printPanelSize();
  }

  private Panel drawPanel = new Panel();
}

class Panel extends JPanel {

  public void printPanelSize() {
    Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
    int w = size.width;
    int h = size.height;
    System.out.println("h = " + h + " w = " + w);
  }

}
```

Comment: *so that I can subsequently calculate the correct dimension of graphics I plan to add* You should probably be learning Swing, not AWT. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html). It will show you how to override the `getPreferredSize()` method so you panel has a default size that can be used by the layout managers of your application.

Comment: That worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
setSize(300, 200);
```

with

```
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
```

and replace

```
 Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
```

with

```
Dimension size = getSize();
```